# Overloading operators for objects that are used to instantiate parameterized roles

Tags: operator-overloading, raku, parametric-polymorphism

In C++ you can create templated classes that use a particular operator on the
templated objects and the class from which these objects are instantiated
must overload that particular operator for its objects to work with the
templated class. For example, the `insertion` method for a BST implementation
might rely on the `<` operator and thus any object to be stored in a BST
must implement that operator.

If possible, how can I do the same with parameterized roles in Raku?

---

In order to provide some context, take for example the following parameterized role defined as its own module:

```
role BST[::T] {
    my role BinaryNode[::T] {
        has T $.item           is rw;
        has BinaryNode $.left  is rw;
        has BinaryNode $.right is rw;
    }

    has BinaryNode $!root;

    method insert( BST:D: T $x --> Nil ) {
        self!rec-insert($x, $!root)
    }

    method !rec-insert( T $x, BinaryNode $node is rw --> Nil ) {
        if !$node.defined     { $node = BinaryNode[$(T)].new(item => $x) }
        elsif $x < $node.item { self!rec-insert($x, $node.left) }
        elsif $node.item < $x { self!rec-insert($x, $node.right) }
        else                  { } # Duplicate; do nothing
    }
}
```

Then, it could be used to store integers:

```
use BST;
my $bst = BST[Int].new;

$bst.insert($_) for 6, 3, 2, 1, 4;
```

However, trying some user-defined type I haven't been able to make it work.
Suppose we've defined a `Point2D` class and the less-than relationship between
two `Point2D` objects is defined by their distance to the center
(e.g., `Point2D.new(:3x, :4x)` is less than `Point2D.new(:6x, :8y)`):

```
use BST;

class Point2D {
    has $.x;
    has $.y;

    multi method distance {
        (($!x - 0) ** 2 ($!y - 0) ** 2).sqrt
    }
}

multi infix:«<»( Point2D:D $lhs, Point2D:D $rhs --> Bool ) {
    return $lhs.distance < $rhs.distance
}

my $bst = BST[Point2D].new;

$bst.insert(Point2D.new(:1x, :4y));
$bst.insert(Point2D.new(:3x, :4y));

=begin comment
Cannot resolve caller Real(Point:D: ); none of these signatures match:
    (Mu:U \v: *%_)
  in method rec-insert ...
  in method insert ...
=end comment
```

My not-so-educated guess is that the operator `<` for `Point2D` is lexical, and thus `BST` doesn't pick it up. [If overloading an operator in  a module, it's recommended to export it so that it will be available to users who `use` or `import` the module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55814306). However, I don't think that makes much sense with `BST` since objects of a particular class will define their relational relationship differently. Furthermore, I'm not even sure if that would work with type captures.

Comment: One way I've done in the past is to define a comparison sub inside your class, say, `sub cmp (Point2D \a, Point2D \b)`.  You can then use that in your exported infixes to avoid code duplication (something like `sub infix:«<»( Point2D \a, Point2D \b) { Point2D.cmp(a,b) == Order::Less }` ).  In parameterization, you can check that such a routine exists and use it for comparison, and failing that, use the standard `cmp` function.  Or allow parameterization with a second optional argument: a comparison method (and note to users that it will fallback to the default `cmp`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is a long-term solution, but why not make the custom type `Cool`?

```
class Point2D is Cool {
    has $.x;
    has $.y;

    multi method distance {
        (($!x - 0) ** 2 + ($!y - 0) ** 2).sqrt
    }
    method Numeric() { self.distance }
    method Int() { self.Numeric.Int }
    method Str() { "$!x,$!y" }
}
```

Then you get all of the regular comparison goodies for free, if you supply the proper methods, like `Numeric`, `Int` and `Str`, to name a few.

Comment: Thanks, Liz! This fits the bill perfectly and like always, in Raku things are a lot simpler than they seem to be at first.

Answer (score 5):

The infix `<` operator is for comparing real numbers.

You want it to numerically compare the value of `.distance`.

Perhaps it makes sense that if you try to use the object as a real number for it to automatically coerce to the distance.

```raku
class Point2D {
    has $.x;
    has $.y;

    method distance {
        (($!x - 0) ** 2 + ($!y - 0) ** 2).sqrt
    }

    method Real { self.distance } # <-----
}
```

Then the built-in `<` automatically does the right thing.

---

Personally I would add a few types and other annotations.
Which also makes `($!x - 0)` and its equivalent `(+$!x)` pointless.

```raku
class Point2D {
    has Real ( $.x, $.y ) is required;

    method distance (--> Real) {
        sqrt( $!x² + $!y² );
    }

    method Real (--> Real) { self.distance }
}
```

---

It might make sense to add a feature to Raku for the generic comparisons (`cmp`, `before`, `after`)

Currently those call `.Stringy` on both values and compare them.

You can abuse this currently, by having a `.Stringy` method which returns something that doesn't do the *Stringy* role.

Perhaps it can be made to work like this:

```raku
role Comparable {
    method COMPARE () {…}
}

class Point does Comparable {
    has Real ( $.x, $.y ) is required;

    method distance (--> Real) {
        sqrt( $!x² + $!y² );
    }

    method COMPARE () {
        ($.distance, $!x, $!y)
    }
}

multi sub infix:<cmp> ( Comparable \left, Comparable \right ) {
    nextsame unless left.WHAT =:= right.WHAT;

    return Same if left =:= right;
    return Same if left eqv right;

    left.COMPARE() cmp right.COMPARE()
}
```

The above would compare by `.distance` then `.x` then `.y`.
(Of course that probably doesn't make that much sense in this case.)